# Tabela no Bootstrap escondendo botões

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Eu estou fazendo uma pequena aplicação Java Web com Bootstrap, mas eu estou com um erro em uma página onde utilizo uma tabela. Quando eu tenho mais de oito linhas na tabela, os botões que ficam abaixo da tabela somem, achei que a página iria ativar o rolamento da página ou o rolamento da tabela em si. Não sei como fazer para fazer o rolamento da página aparecer. Segue abaixo o código, o preenchimento dele é através do Java, mas vou inserir algumas linhas como hardcode pra efeito de visualização, que é o meu problema.

PS: Não estou conseguindo fazer o código utilizar o Boostrap aqui na página do StackOverFlow, o que eu acho estranho, já que no código eu faço referência a links de estilização online e não uso links de arquivos locais. Por isso vou colocar a imagem da execução na minha máquina também.

Código Original

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Odonto Cascadura</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
     <link href="sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: #4682B4; border-color: #4682B4;">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Painel</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Agenda</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Pacientes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Profissionais</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Financeiro</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Relatórios</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Configurações</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </header>
   <div class="content-wrapper"> 
    <section class="content">
      <main>
       <div class="box-header with-border">
         <h3 class="box-title col-md-12">Pacientes</h3>
       </div>
       <!-- /.box-header -->
       <table class="table table-hover" overflow="scroll">
        <thead> 
         <tr> 
          <th> </th>
          <th>Id</th> 
          <th>Nome</th> 
          <th>CPF</th>
          <th>RG</th>
         </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody>
         <c:forEach var="paciente" items="${pacientes}">
          <tr data-href="#"> 
           <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="mvc?logica=RemoverPacienteLogica&id_paciente=${paciente.id_paciente}">Remover</a></td> <td>${paciente.id_paciente}</td> <td>${paciente.nome_paciente}</td> <td>${paciente.rg}</td> <td>${paciente.cpf}</td> 
          </tr> 
         </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
       </table>
       <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.table tr[data-href]').each(function(){
                $(this).css('cursor','pointer').hover(
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).addClass('active'); 
                    },  
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).removeClass('active'); 
                    }).click( function(){ 
                        document.location = $(this).attr('data-href'); 
                    }
                );
            });
        });
       </script>
       
       <!-- /.tabpanel 3 -->
       <!-- <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
          <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#aba1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aba2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aba3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
         </ul> 
       </nav> 
       <script>
        submitForms = function(){
         document.getElementById("form1").submit();
        }
       </script> -->     
      </main>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Novo Procedimento</button>
      <a href="mvc?logica=NovoPacienteLogica" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">Novo Paciente</a>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  <footer class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" style="background-color: #4682B4; border-color: #4682B4;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
   <p class="text-muted"><font color="#FFFFFF"> Odontologia</font></p>
    </div>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Código com hardcodes para questões de visibilidade

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Odonto Cascadura</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
     <link href="sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: #4682B4; border-color: #4682B4;">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Painel</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Agenda</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Pacientes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Profissionais</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Financeiro</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Relatórios</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF">Configurações</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </header>
   <div class="content-wrapper"> 
    <section class="content">
      <main>
       <div class="box-header with-border">
         <h3 class="box-title col-md-12">Pacientes</h3>
       </div>
       <!-- /.box-header -->
       <table class="table table-hover" overflow="scroll">
        <thead> 
         <tr> 
          <th> </th>
          <th>Id</th> 
          <th>Nome</th> 
          <th>CPF</th>
          <th>RG</th>
         </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody>
         <tr data-href="#"> 
          <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Remover</a></td> <td>1</td> <td>aaaa</td> <td>1111</td> <td>2222</td></tr> 
<tr data-href="#"> 
          <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Remover</a></td> <td>1</td> <td>aaaa</td> <td>1111</td> <td>2222</td></tr>
<tr data-href="#"> 
          <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Remover</a></td> <td>1</td> <td>aaaa</td> <td>1111</td> <td>2222</td></tr>
<tr data-href="#"> 
          <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Remover</a></td> <td>1</td> <td>aaaa</td> <td>1111</td> <td>2222</td></tr>
<tr data-href="#"> 
          <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Remover</a></td> <td>1</td> <td>aaaa</td> <td>1111</td> <td>2222</td></tr>
<tr data-href="#"> 
          <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Remover</a></td> <td>1</td> <td>aaaa</td> <td>1111</td> <td>2222</td></tr>
<tr data-href="#"> 
          <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Remover</a></td> <td>1</td> <td>aaaa</td> <td>1111</td> <td>2222</td></tr>
<tr data-href="#"> 
          <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Remover</a></td> <td>1</td> <td>aaaa</td> <td>1111</td> <td>2222</td></tr>
<tr data-href="#"> 
          <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Remover</a></td> <td>1</td> <td>aaaa</td> <td>1111</td> <td>2222</td></tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
       <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.table tr[data-href]').each(function(){
                $(this).css('cursor','pointer').hover(
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).addClass('active'); 
                    },  
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).removeClass('active'); 
                    }).click( function(){ 
                        document.location = $(this).attr('data-href'); 
                    }
                );
            });
        });
       </script>
       
       <!-- /.tabpanel 3 -->
       <!-- <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
          <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#aba1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aba2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aba3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
         </ul> 
       </nav> 
       <script>
        submitForms = function(){
         document.getElementById("form1").submit();
        }
       </script> -->     
      </main>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Novo Procedimento</button>
      <a href="mvc?logica=NovoPacienteLogica" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">Novo Paciente</a>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  <footer class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" style="background-color: #4682B4; border-color: #4682B4;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
   <p class="text-muted"><font color="#FFFFFF"> Odontologia</font></p>
    </div>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Página com tabela com 8 registros

[image: Página da tabela com 8 registros]

Página da tabela com menos de 8 registros

[image: Página da tabela com menos de 8 registros]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas não sei se essa solução te atende pq não sei como o sistema deve funcionar para uma boa experiencia. Mas consegui uma solução para vc.

**Opção 1**

Com essa opção vc pode deixar os BTNs fixos logo acima do `footer`, ai mesmo só tem duas linhas na tabela os BTNs continuariam na parte de baixo da tela. Para isso fiz da seguinte forma. *(que ainda não acho o ideal, mas por algum motivo quando sua tabela não está aceitando overflow nem height abaixo tem uma imagem sobre isso)*

CSS na Tabela com uma `margin-bottom:120px;` descontando a altura dos BTNs e do Footer e uma `<div class="container">` com os BTNs logo acima do `footer`

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 120px;
}

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom" style="padding: 10px 0 60px 21px; background-color: #fff;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Novo Procedimento</button>
                    <a href="mvc?logica=NovoPacienteLogica" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">Novo Paciente</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<footer ....
```

**Resultado nas imagens:** *(com poucos e muitos resultados na tabela)*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo que fiz direto no site do Bootstrap. Porém sua tabela não aceitou esses estilos... ***(repare nos boxes vermelhos)***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Opção 2**

Eu coloquei os BTNs dentro de uma div e coloquei nela uma `"margin-bottom: 80px"` maior que a altura do Footer e deu certo.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 80px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Novo Procedimento</button>
    <a href="mvc?logica=NovoPacienteLogica" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">Novo Paciente</a>
</div>
```

O Snippet não está funcionando mas segue uma img. Testa ai! *(repare nos BTNs e no Scroll a direita.)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Me atende sim Hugo. Mas se eu quisesse manter os botões fixos? Com a barra rolando apenas a tabela, como eu faria?

Comment: @LucasFerreira acredito que dá pra fazer sim. Teria problema se eles ficarem logo acima do footer fixos, mesmo que só tivesse dois resultados na tabela por exemplo?

Comment: Não haveria problemas.

Comment: @LucasFerreira editei a resposta e coloquei na **Opção 1** a proposta dos BTNs sempre no final da página, tem alguns detalhes nessa opção, mas por hora pode te atender. A **Opção 2** é com os BTNs lá no final do Scroll.